# Serialize a type without its type-tag

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

is there any possibility that I serialize an object without needing to add its actual root-tag too. This sounds a bit curious, so I´m appending some code that´ll explain what I mean:

```
class Test {
    public MyClass M;
}

class MyClass {
    public int A;
    public int B;
}
```

The members A and B should now not serialize to M but to the Root-class `Test` as of the following:

```
<Test>
  <A>3</A>
  <B>4</B>
</Test>
```

I need this as I have many empty dummy-classes that simply derived from a base-class but adding no members at all where I want to avoid serialization of that inner dummy-type. Is this possible?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking but your classes and xml will serialise.

Comment: I know it will serialize, but not the way I want. Currently it would serialize to <Test><MyClass>
  <A>3</A>
  <B>4</B></MyClass>
</Test> but I want to push the data from MyClass to Test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`XmlSerializer` by default does not support this behavior. The class can implement `IXmlSerializable` or create the document from an `XDocument`.

See: [XML serialization of a nested object, but at the root level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989669/xml-serialization-of-a-nested-object-but-at-the-root-level)

```
public string Serialize(Test test)
{
    var document =
        new XDocument(
            new XElement("Test",
                new XElement("A", test.M.A),
                new XElement("B", test.M.B)));

    return document.ToString();
}

var test = new Test {  M = new MyClass { A = 1, B = 2 } };

Console.WriteLine(Serialize(test));
```

Outputs:

```
<Test>
  <A>1</A>
  <B>2</B>
</Test>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is impossible to do this with **XmlSerializer** class. But you always can use **XmlReader** and **XmlWriter** to serialize and deserialize your data manually.